# Symfony2 custom query in entity orm

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine

In controller

```
 return $this->render(
                'FrontBundle:Default:search.html.twig',
                array(
                    'edition'     => $edition,       THIS ONE
                    'paginator'   => $pagination,
                    'array_ed_id' => $editions_search,
                    'array_he_id' => $heading_search,
                    'text'        => $text,
                    'seo'         => $seo,
                    'result'      => $result,
                    'testix'      => 10
                )
            );
```

in Twig i need custom query value.getCount to count rows

```
    {% for value in edition %}
    <label><label class="" for="front_form_edition_s_{{ value.getId }}">
{{ value.getName }}</label>{{value.getCount}}</label>
```

in Edition entity i add custom function:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;
..........................
class Edition {
..........................
    public function getCount()
    {

        $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
        $query = $entityManager->createNativeQuery('select count(*) from advert_edition where edition_id= ?', $rsm);
        $query->setParameter(1, '16');

        $users = $query->getResult();
        return 10;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work! :( Please tell me how i can do that.

Comment: Where is the issue ?

Comment: He's missing the brackets on the method call.

Comment: I think it's wrong to make a query inside an entity. For me you must do `{{value.advertEdition|length}}` or create a custom method inside your entityRepository.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the "count" property in your object, then:

```
{{ value.getCount() }}
```

or if you have the count property and "getCount" is the only getter:

```
{{ value.count }}
```

Comment: `{{value.count}}` try to make `$value->count`, `$value->getCount()` and `$value->isCount()`.

Answer (score 0):

For this case i found another solution, i created twig extension Count

```
public function countEdition($id)
{
     $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Test") or die("Could not connect in CountExt: " . mysql_error());
     mysql_select_db('Express',$connection)or die("Could not connect in CountExt: " . mysql_error());
     $query="select count(*) from advert_edition where edition_id=$id";
     $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Bad query CountExt: ' . mysql_error());
     $count=mysql_fetch_row($result);
     return $count[0];
}
```

And in twig:

```
{% for value in edition %}
<label><label class="" for="front_form_edition_s_{{ value.getId }}">{{ value.getName }}</label>{{value.getId|count}}</label>
{% endfor %}
```